# Is there a way to programmatically change the Mac address on a phone?

Tags: java, android

I want to somehow dynamically change the MAC addresses of the devices to prevent tracking.

Answer (score 2):

the `MAC address` is semi-hard coded into the NIC (Network Interface Card)

So you can just **Spoof** the `Mac Address` on android.and for changing, maybe you need to access to the part of the hardware.
and *you cannot change it programmatically*

http://androidforums.com/threads/changing-spoofing-mac-address.3506/

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2620741